# How to handle unexpected blank space when splitting String by blank space in Java

Tags: java, string, substring, whitespace, delimiter

I am ingesting a file line by line and each line has a varying number of space delimited strings as seen below.  This is a single row from the file.  The code works as expected except for the case of this line where there is an unexpected space like in El Paso here: `EL PASO*TX*K4`.  I'd use defined indexes for each string if there were a fixed number of strings per row but there are not.  Some rows will have as few as 7 strings where others have as many as 21 strings to ingest. Any one have a good idea on how to best handle this situation?

`NAV3ELP VORTAC              ALIBY*NM*K2                         ANJIE*TX*K4                         CINAG*TX*K4                         EL PASO*TX*K4                       FABAN*TX*K4                         FANNY*TX*K4                         FARCY*TX*K4                         FEMOL*TX*K4                         FIGMO*TX*K4                         GIFEN*TX*K4                         GREBE*NM*K2                         HANCH*NM*K2                         JIDEN*TX*K4                         KEYLO*TX*K4                         LINZY*TX*K4                         NOCIG*TX*K4                         NUQUH*TX*K4                         PIERS*TX*K4                         RIOWE*TX*K4                         RISGE*TX*K4                         RUTER*NM*K2`

```
    public Nav3Data parseRecord(String dataLine) {
        // check record type
        if(!dataLine.startsWith("NAV3")) return null;

        Nav3Data theNav = new Nav3Data();
        // parse Navaid ID
        theNav.setNavaidID(dataLine.substring(NAVAID_ID_START_IDX, NAVAID_ID_END_IDX).trim());
        // parse fixes
        String[] fixes = dataLine.substring(FIX_IDS_START_IDX, FIX_IDS_END_IDX).split("\\s+"); 
        theNav.setFixIDs(fixes);
        return theNav;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split on 2 spaces or more:

```
dataLine.substring(FIX_IDS_START_IDX, FIX_IDS_END_IDX).split("\\s{2,}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options: 
a) Either split on more than one white space characters
b) If the white space between sections is known and constant, split explicitly on that value.

Comment: More than one white space character is the solution I was after but wasn't familiar with the syntax for doing so.  Thanks!